# Positioning an overlay produces a different outcome to drawtext with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image overlay I'm positioning using the equation: `overlay=1015:(((H-h)/2) + 225 + 60)` which works as expected.

However, when I try and apply this to drawtext `x=1045:y=(((H-h)/2) + 225 + 60)` it doesn't position at the same y coordinate?

Are there any nuances people know about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay and drawtext filters have different variable names.

Assuming you mean `H` to refer to the height of the frame and `h` and the height of the text, you would replace `h` with `th`. Both `H` and
`h` refer to the frame height in drawtext.

```
x=1045:y=(((H-th)/2) + 225 + 60)
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. `h` is the height of the overlay, and `th` would be the height of the text. Got it.

Comment: Yes. The `225+60` will offset it from the center.